# Rails is not installing any gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, ruby-on-rails-5

Whenever i try to install any gem and bundle install it it gives me:
[image]

following bundle instructions to `bundle update rails`(which i shouldn't do it suppose) i get:
[image: <code>bundle update rails</code>]

Comment: try to install rails gem first `gem install rails -v 5.0.1`

Comment: but i've already installed version 5.0.1 when i started this project.

Comment: Have you tried removing Gemfile.lock file first? is it the output of `bundle update` or `bundle install`?

Comment: @TalhaMeh As Anwar told you need to try by remove Gemfile.lock  then try bundle install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STEPS TO RESOLVE THIS :-

1. Remove the Gemfile.lock
2. Run the bundle install.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to run `bundle update`

Comment: i've already stated **bundle update rails** doesnt work. While **bundle update** will update all gems which i dont want.